# A service to check Server Push Notifications

Tags: android, service, server, notifications

I am developing mobile app that needs to send users push notifications. I planned to use Google Cloud Messaging service (Firebase) , but I assume that I will have many users , and afraid to reach the Firebase Spark plan (free one), and I know that it is really expensive.
What was alternative plan for me , we to set the mobile app check my server database and reads notifications from it. into the server level this is done sucessfully.
Question :

- Is my approach logic ? Am I missing something ?. Is this the best solution ?
- If so , I need to develop a Android service that will check  server for
  notification , eg every 1 hour. Which android service type to use ? I
  have ready that recent android version will kill my service. will
  Foreground service service ? , shall I use alarm?

Thanks

Comment: I don't find any limit in FCM mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: one more thing that pushes me to use server based Notifications, is that  I need my app to get  database update from server. I mean that on a daily basis ,android app at client end will connect to server and download databse updated, if found. updated data size is quite small.(less than 2 kb).